# How to access elements by using pointer instead of array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've this piece of code which is working by now(at least):

```
int** constructSparseMatrix(int totalRow, int totalCol, int totalEl) {
    int** arr = new int*[totalEl];
    //int x = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < totalEl; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[totalCol];
        for (int k = 0; k < totalCol; k++) {
            if(k == totalCol - 1) {
                arr[i][totalCol - 1] = rand () % 101;
            } else {
                arr[i][k] = rand () % totalRow + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

and I'm trying to access the element inside by using pointer instead of array and here is my try:

```
int** constructSparseMatrix(int *totalRow, int *totalCol, int totalEl) {
    int** arr = new int*[totalEl];
    //int x = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < totalEl; i++) {
        arr[i] = &totalCol [0];
        for (int k = 0; k < *totalCol; k++) {
            if(k == *totalCol - 1) {
                arr[i][*totalCol - 1] = rand () % 101;
            } else {
                arr[i][k] = rand () % *totalRow + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

But when I initialize the same way as the working function:

```
int** arr = constructSparseMatrix(5,3,totalEl);
```

then I receive this error:

```
argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int *"
```

First of all, is my conversion from array to pointer version coded properly? If it's correct, how can I initialize it to avoid above error?

Comment: You keep saying pointer instead of array, but I don't think it means what you think it means. You were never using arrays, you were using a value that, probably, means how many elements there are in a column and in a row. And you replaced that value with a pointer. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the point of your change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is obvious that this statement in the function

```
arr[i] = &totalCol [0];
```

is wrong. It does not make sense.

You declared the function

```
int** constructSparseMatrix(int *totalRow, int *totalCol, int totalEl);
```

as having the first and second parameters as pointers but are trying to pass integer literals 5 and 3 to it in the call

```
int** arr = constructSparseMatrix(5,3,totalEl);
```

You could write for example

```
int totalRow = 5;
int totalCol = 3;
```

//...

```
int** arr = constructSparseMatrix( &totalRow, &totalCol, totalEl );
```

But I do not see a sense to declare these parameters like pointers because they are in fact constants within the function that is they are not changed.

And the variable names confuse the reader. For example I would expect that `totalRow` is used within the function in statement

```
int** arr = new int*[totalRow];
```

instead of `totalEl`

If you want to use pointers within the function then the function can look like

```
int** constructSparseMatrix( int totalRow, int totalCol, int totalEl ) 
{
    int** arr = new int*[totalEl];

    for ( int **p = arr; p < arr + totalEl; ++p ) 
    {
        *p = new int[totalCol];
        for ( int *q = *p; q < *p + totalCol; ++q ) 
        {
            if ( q == *p + totalCol - 1 ) 
            {
                *q = rand () % 101;
            } 
            else 
            {
                *q = rand () % totalRow + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: So I don't need to make any change to my initial version since it's already correct?

Comment: @Pewds if the usage of totalRow and totalEl is correct then the function is correct.

Comment: Hi vlad, I have this error: `a value of type "int **" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int *"` at  `int *q = p`. Is there something wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing constants 5 and 3 as arguments which causes this error.
you can't pass constant value as it is by reference.Try passing 5 and 3 by storing them in a variable.